# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda introducir un intervalo de números, en una función?

Tags: java

He creado un programa con un intervalo predeterminado en el cual el usuario introduce un número y le dice si está dentro del intervalo o no. Ahora bien, quiero saber como se hace para que el usuario pueda introducir el intervalo que el quiera dentro de esta función.

Código:

```
public class Ejercicio {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        int num;
        int interva;
        System.out.println("Introduzca un numero en decimal");
        num=sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca el intervalo a desear");
        interva=sc.nextInt();


        System.out.println(Intervalo(num,/*interva*/));

    }

    public static int Intervalo(int numero, /*int intervalo, este parametro esta includo 
            en la cabecera de la función para poder hacer que el usuario introduzca
            el intervalo que desee.*/){



        if(numero>0 && <9){// De esta forma lo que pongo es un intervalo predeterminado, ahora megustaria hacerlo para que el usuario introdzca el que quiera*/){
            System.out.println("El numero esta dentro del intervalo");
        }else{
            System.out.println("El numero esta fuera del intervalo");

        }
        return intervalo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La manera más simple pero poco elegante de hacerlo seria

```
public class Ejercicio
{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

    int num;
    int intervaMin;
    int intervaMax;

    System.out.println("Introduzca un numero en decimal");
    num=sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Introduzca el mínimo del intervalo a desear");
    intervaMin=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Introduzca el máximo del intervalo a desear");
    intervaMax=sc.nextInt();

    Intervalo(num, intervaMin, intervaMax);
  }

  public static void Intervalo(int numero, int min, int max)
  {
    if(numero>min && numero<max)
    {
        System.out.println("El numero esta dentro del intervalo");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("El numero esta fuera del intervalo");
    }
   }
 }
```

Podrias proveer al usuario con un formato en el cual poner el intervalo y usar eso con funciones como metodos como `String.split()`

Comment: Gracias ya lo resolví por mi cuenta. Ese metodo no lo puedo usar.

Comment: @josemanuel Alguna razon en especifico por la que no puedes usar el metodo?